# Delphi firebird autoinc

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, firebird, firebird2.1

How do I make an autoinc field in firebird with Zeos.

-Brad

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the SQL you attempted to use to do this from the FAQ #29 question.    As that should have worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is explained in [Firebird FAQ #29](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq29/). See the bottom of that page.

Comment: Didn't work, I had already tried that..  I might have done something wrong...  I am using v7 alpha

Comment: @Brad: "Didn't work" is meaningless. If you want help, give specifics about what you tried and what exactly "didn't work" means. Otherwise, you're just wasting your (and our) time, which does no one any good.

Comment: Sorry Ken, but the example did not work with zeos db 7.  It does not autoinc.  I get a SQL error, not sure what it was exactly, on a different computer, post the demo code I did when i get back to the other computer.

Comment: Went through everything again, I guess I had missed something..  not sure exactly what I did wrong but it works this time.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what do you mean by "making an autoinc field in firebird with Zeos". The autoinc fields and a whole database structure are usually defined in SQL script that can be executed by a lot of tools. I have used Firebird 2.1 in my recent project (using FibPlus 6.9.9) and have written several posts about it, maybe the following will help:

[Part 1 - Introduction](http://sergworks.wordpress.com/2010/03/25/delphi-firebird-fibplus-part-1-introduction/)

[Part 4 - Autoincrement Fields](http://sergworks.wordpress.com/2010/03/29/delphi-firebird-fibplus-part-4-autoincrement-fields/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use mru kind component. or a combobox with items filled.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had a type-o I wanted to say Autoinc instead of autocomplete.  I've edited the post.